# How can I access port 8001 with a proxy server even when it's not open?

Tags: proxy, kubectl

So I did the following:

```
minikube dashboard    
kubectl proxy
```

And it says `Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001`, however this port is not open on my VM (not included in my firewall rules)

[image]

then how am I able to access it via ssh tunneling?

Basically I did this:

```
ssh -L 12345:localhost:8001 myLogin@myRemoteServer
```

And then accessed it as:

```
http://localhost:12345/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#/pod?namespace=default
```

Comment: Could you add more information to the question: where is your vm (computer, cloud), from what machine you try to connect minikube  with SSH (VM, your computer,...), some details about the vm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this helpful `kubectl proxy --address='0.0.0.0' --disable-filter=true`